# Force some child elements to right side

Tags: css, flexbox

There are four child divs. These are visible in desktop like this way:

```
First Text | Second Text | Third Text | Fourth Text
```

In mobile, they will be like this way:

```
First Text  |  Third Text
Second Text |  Fourth Text
```

HTML structure of this block:

```
<div class="col one">First Text</div>
<div class="col two">Second Text</div>
<div class="col three">Third Text</div>
<div class="col fourth">Fourth Text</div>
```

I am able to achieve this scenario in multiple ways. But, the problem is, it's an existing project at where **I am not allowed to modify any HTML structure**. Is this scenario possible with CSS only (something like css flex or other way)?

N:B: height of divs are dynamic, so using `position: absolute;` won't be suitable. I even tried calculating div height with jQuery and use those value for positioning other divs. But, as the data, elements etc are coming from dynamic way (something like ng-repeat way of angularjs), I could not get those value after page load. For those kind of complexity, **I am finding proper CSS solution** (if there are any).

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f95mqs8L/3/)**

**Update:**

I forgot to mention one thing. Sorry for that. There will be no extra vertical space between two divs.

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f95mqs8L/6/)** (by @Johannes)

Comment: "heights are dynamic", so how should they have to be aligned in mobile?

Comment: Your css seems to work fine if you change this `.col {
      width: 50%;
      float: none;
    }` to this `.col {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }` - https://jsfiddle.net/f95mqs8L/4/

Comment: Second div should be under First div, Fourth div should be under third div.

Comment: You can change your `HTML` around a little and have your first 2 `div` inside a row and the second 2 `div` in there own row like this and you get the right sort of result, but it depends on how flexible you are with the HTML - https://jsfiddle.net/f95mqs8L/7/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you can use FlexBox, you can use the `order` to make it work:

```css
body {display: flex;}
.col {width: 25%;}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {width: 50%;}
  .one {order: 1;}
  .two {order: 3;}
  .three {order: 2;}
  .fourth {order: 4;}
}
```

```html
<div class="col one">First Text</div>
<div class="col two">Second Text</div>
<div class="col three">Third Text</div>
<div class="col fourth">Fourth Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with flexbox:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpmQYd

You define the container as flex-container:

```
.row { display: flex }
```

In the media queries you add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to that to allow the two lines.

Then you add `order` settings to the child elements (in the media queries):

```
.one {
    order: 1;
  }
  .two {
    order: 3;
  }
  .three {
    order: 2;
  }
  .fourth {
    order: 4;
  }
```

And not to forget: erase all the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Like this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Postgraduate students</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      .col {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          .col {
            width: 50%;

          }

        }
  </style>
</head>
<body align = "center">

<div class="col one">First Text</div>
<div class="col two">Second Text</div>
<div class="col three">Third Text</div>
<div class="col fourth">Fourth Text</div>
 </body>
```